# Concat strings in a textblock with static ressources (without bindings)

Tags: wpf, string, string-concatenation, concatenation, textblock

i try doing something like this:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static localization:localization.Offset}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0} A"/>
```

the result of this line is: "Offset A"

i would like to do that with a textblock. is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={x:Static localization:localization.Offset}, 
    StringFormat={}{0} A}" />
```

Comment: OP says "without bindings". You give an answer with bindings. OP accepts... sure, makes sense

Comment: The OP doesn't know what he wants, i think he wants this.

Comment: To be honest, I didn't even see the *without bindings* in the title until just now, but thanks for pointing that out. I'm not actually sure that this can be accomplished *without bindings* anyway.

Comment: without binding to the VM. sorry for missunderstanding.